# linear transformation - need help

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:V\to V$

$T_1:P_1[R]\to P_1[R]$

$T_1(ax+b) = -bx+(2a-3b)$

I need to find if there's a base of eigenvectors and their values.
How can I solve this? What should I do?

Comment: Help Please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to write down a matrix for $T_1$. Of course this matrix will depend on a choice of basis of $V$. I'll use the basis $\{1, x\}$. The matrix I get under this basis is
$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-3 && 2\\
-1 && 0
\end{array}\right)$ (I'll leave you to show why). From here, it's a standard exercise to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues (don't forget that your eigenvectors are actually polynomials!).

Comment: I get the transpose of the matrix you have above.  Is your matrix acting on column vectors by left multiplication, or row vectors by right multiplication?

Comment: My matrix is acting in the usual way. I'm guessing you used the basis $\{x, 1\}$ rather than $\{1, x\}$

Comment: Nope, you're the one who used the basis $\{x, 1\}$.  $T(1) = -3 - x$.  My matrix gives
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & -2\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
while yours gives $(-3,2)^T$.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Edited my post. Of course, $T_1(x) = 2$, so your second column should be $(2, 0)^T$

Comment: Yes, that's a typo.  It's supposed to be the transpose of what you originally had.